# J2ME backlight

Tags: java-me, mobile, backlight

Is there any reliable way to support back-light in J2ME on multitude of models, other then pre-processing?

Is there any library available that may handle the back-light for various phones out there?
Regards.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a direct control as in Nokia UI API, but there is a method in MIDP that controls backlight, it is `Display.flashBacklight(int duration)`. Unfortunately, phones are not obliged to obey this method. But this method is at least part of MIDP, not some proprietary API.

Comment: I used @Malcolm's flashBackLight() as a workaround to keep the backlight on continuously. I called this code in a TimerTask scheduled every 5 seconds:
[code start]
Display.getDisplay(this).flashBacklight(1);
Display.getDisplay(this).flashBacklight(0);
[code end]
Found to work on Nokia 3120 classic (Symbian S40).

Comment: Also see http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?114991-How-to-keep-backlight-on-solution.

Comment: Display.flashBacklight works fine on some S40 devices (at least 5th ed) but does not do anything on S60 (at least 3rd ed)

Answer (score 2):

Native backlight management on phones ranges from the completely natural to the obviously insane.

It's also nowhere in the MIDP specifications.

The Nokia UI API allows to work around some issues and is actually present on non-Nokia phones.