# Is there a way in j2me, or at least on nokia phones, to light up the screen after screen saver kicks in?

Tags: java-me, screen, nokia, midp, screensaver

I have a midlet which checks some conditions and at some point, when some condition becomes true, I display a pop-up dialog to the user.
If nothing happens for a while, the screen saver kicks in and after that the pop-up is not shown to the user - the screen is simply dark.
Is there  way to wake up from the screen saving mode programmatically?

I know I can alert the user by sound and vibration and I do that, but I'd like to be able
to get the screen to react in some way (either to flash the lights, or just turn the light on).
Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Please check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860540/j2me-backlight

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `showNotify()` and `hideNotify()` from the `Canvas` class.